# Licensing using c++ strings and cout

Tags: licensing, mit

I am creating a library for c++ on github. I want to release it under [mit license](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT), but several times i use lines of code like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

cout << "whatever";
string myString;
```

My project will not contain any binaries, only source code + makefile.

As I am not directly copy + pasting stl, only assuming that local compilers will have it, what legal blurb /licensing details do I have to include?

[This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/228187/licensing-using-standard-c-library) is a similar question, but it has to do with C standard library, which is released (as I understand it) under a different license.

Comment: _Your_ C++ STL might be available under the Apache License; that certainly [doesn't mean they all are](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/license.html).

Comment: Duly noted, Ive edited my post, but my earlier question still stands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are not distributing any copy of a standard library, there are no licensing details for the standard library that you *can* include, as you can't know which implementation your users will use and whatever you state would likely be incorrect for some users.

This would change when you start to distribute binaries, because then you know which implementation of the standard library those binaries were built against and thus what licensing requirements apply.